# How to get object values with dynamic variable from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to get the value of an object field from JSON. I have a dynamic variable `let check_permission_key = 'ratingscalename';` and have one JSON

```
let overwrite_key = {
  studentimage: 'student',
  ratingscalename: 'rating-scale-name',
  ratingscale: 'rating-scale-name',
  capturesettingset: 'capture-setting-set',
  capturesetting: 'capture-setting-set',
  eventlog: 'event-log',
  goalcategorie: 'goal-category',
  userimage: 'user',
  datasheetlink: 'datasheet',
  datasheetgoal: 'datasheet',
};

let get_value = overwrite_key.check_permission_key;
```

So I am fetching the data like this, but it is not working can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access the object property value using a variable use [**`Bracket ([]) notation`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation):

```js
let overwrite_key = {'studentimage':'student','ratingscalename':'rating-scale-name','ratingscale':'rating-scale-name','capturesettingset':'capture-setting-set','capturesetting':'capture-setting-set','eventlog':'event-log','goalcategorie':'goal-category','userimage':'user','datasheetlink':'datasheet','datasheetgoal':'datasheet'};
let check_permission_key = 'ratingscalename';
let get_value = overwrite_key[check_permission_key];
console.log(get_value);
```

Comment: thanks it is working now

Comment: @NikulPanchal, you are most welcome:)

Answer (score 3):

Objects in `javascript` are pretty much arrays with String keys, so you can access a dynamic property like this:

```
let get_value = overwrite_key[check_permission_key];
```

Comment: ohhh thanks, it is working now

Answer (score -1):

You can use `eval()` function.

```js
let overwrite_key = {
  studentimage: 'student',
  ratingscalename: 'rating-scale-name',
  ratingscale: 'rating-scale-name',
  capturesettingset: 'capture-setting-set',
  capturesetting: 'capture-setting-set',
  eventlog: 'event-log',
  goalcategorie: 'goal-category',
  userimage: 'user',
  datasheetlink: 'datasheet',
  datasheetgoal: 'datasheet',
};
let check_permission_key = 'ratingscalename';
let get_value = eval(`overwrite_key.${check_permission_key}`);
console.log(get_value);
```

[JavaScript eval() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

Comment: You should avoid `eval`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!

Comment: Yes, you are right. But it can be a solution in some situations.